# How to query the columns when taking dump from a single table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dump

I have a table in the Postgres database called `drf_api_logs`, and I want to filter this table and dump data.

This is the filter I try to apply:

```
two_month_ago = datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=60)
APILogsModel.objects.filter(~Q(added_on__date__gte=two_month_ago))
```

I want to dump data like this:

```
cmd = f'PGPASSWORD={config("DB_PASSWORD")} /usr/bin/pg_dump --dbname={config("DB_NAME")} --table=drf_api_logs --file={dir}/{log_name} --username={config("DB_USER")} --host={config("DB_HOST")} --port=5432'
```

How can I do this filtering when dumping?

I tried like this, but it's not working:

```
month_ago = datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=60)
today = datetime.now().date()

cmd = f'PGPASSWORD={config("DB_PASSWORD")} /usr/bin/pg_dump --dbname={config("DB_NAME")} --table=drf_api_logs --where=added_on__date BETWEEN {today} AND {month_ago} --file={dir}/{log_name} --username={config("DB_USER")} --host={config("DB_HOST")} --port=5432'
```

Comment: the maunal show no such optioon https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html make a dump_table with the wanted column and export that

Comment: tables have columns and rows, no fields

Comment: You can't use `pg_dump` to do that. You can do that using [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) to create a CSV file.